# Extending a long-lived (60 day) user access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I'm using FB login, converting the access token to a long-lived one on a server and then storing it in a database. According to the docs [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension), making a request using this access token should keep it valid for another 60 days.

I'm making a request to /[userID]/picture every 4 hours for every user (with access_token, client_id, client_secret) provided. However, the tokens still say they're expiring on the date 60 days from creation.

I've also tried the following code as I've seen on other StackOverflow answers, but the new token it generates isn't extended by 60 days. These answers link to [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/) (dead link).

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.x/oauth/access_token?             
  client_id=APP_ID&
  client_secret=APP_SECRET&
  grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
  fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

**TLDR**: How can I extend a long-lived token without the user having to log in again? Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/expiration-and-extension:

> Refreshing Long-Lived Tokens
>
> Even the long-lived access token will eventually expire. At any point, you can generate a new long-lived token by sending the person back to the login flow used by your web app - note that the person will not actually need to login again, they have already authorized your app, so they will immediately redirect back to your app from the login flow with a refreshed token - how this appears to the person will vary based on the type of login flow that you are using, for example if you are using the JavaScript SDK, this will take place in the background, if you are using a server-side flow, the browser will quickly redirect to the Login Dialog and then automatically and immediately back to your app again.
>
> After doing the above you will obtain a new short-lived token and then you need to perform the same exchange for a long-lived token as above.

So it looks like it's not possible to renew the long-lived token without getting a new short-lived one (which requires user interaction)

Auto-renewal on request is only available for native mobile apps (Android/iOS):

> Native mobile apps using Facebook's SDKs will get long-lived access tokens, good for about 60 days. These tokens will be refreshed once per day when the person using your app makes a request to Facebook's servers. If no requests are made, the token will expire after about 60 days and the person will have to go through the login flow again to get a new token.

Answer (score -1):

All you have to do is to go [HERE](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken) and paste your **short token**, then press the button **Extend Access Token** and a new token will be **generated**.
Than you have to use the **new token** and not the old, cause the **old** is the **short lived token**.

Hope it helps ^_^

Comment: I already have a long-token, the form you linked doesn't have a button to extend it. Is there a way to extend a long-lived token?